jsPdf Export not Exporting class declared CSS
how do I apply a check on a  class check?
I have the following html5 logic. My style applies the format to my razor page view.
I want to apply the css setting, can I add any ID fields into my  somehow?
    

    <style>
    .billable {
        background-color: #e2efda; 
    }

    .nonbillable_row{
        background-color: #ddebf7;
    }

    .week_row{
        background-color: #fce4d6;
    }
   .title_row{
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #e7e7e9;
    }

</style> 


This class is then assigned to a table row.


    <div id="timesheetset1">
   
    <table  class="display nowrap table table-bordered" style="width:95%">
            <thead>
                <tr class="title_row">
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.code)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.billable)</th>
                    <th>Project</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.taskName)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.comments)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.afterHours)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.work)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.assigneeDisplayName)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.start)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.billingTYPE)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.status)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.summaryRootCause)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.TimesheetSingle.declinedReason)</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    @if(Model.TitleTimesheet1 == null)
                    {
                    <th></th>
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    <th colspan="13" class="week_row">@Model.TitleTimesheet1</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="font-size:x-small">
                @if (Model.BTimesheet1.Count > 0)
                {
                    <tr class="billable" data-row-type="billable">
                        <th>Billable</th>
                        <th>Billable</th>
                        <th>Billable</th>
                        <th>Billable</th>
                        <th>Total Billable timesheets: (@Model.BTimesheet1.Count)</th>                        
                        <th></th>
                        <th>
                            @{
                                double SumHours = Model.BTimesheet1.Sum(item => item.work);
                                <text>@SumHours.ToString("F2")</text>
                            }
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Billable</th>
                        <th>Billable</th>
                        <th>Billable</th>
                        <th>Billable</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.BTimesheet1)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)</td>
                            <td>@(item.billable ? "Billable" : "Non-Billable")</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.projectExternalName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.taskName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.afterHours)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.work)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.assigneeDisplayName)</td>
                            <td>@DateTime.Parse(item.start).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.billingTYPE)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.summaryRootCause)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.declinedReason)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                @if (Model.NBTimesheet1.Count > 0)
                {
                    <tr class="nonbillable" data-row-type="nonbillable">
                    <th>Non-Billable</th>
                    <th>Non-Billable</th>
                    <th>Non-Billable</th>
                    <th>Non-Billable</th>
                    <th>Total Billable timesheets: (@Model.NBTimesheet1.Count)</th>                    
                        <th></th>
                        <th>
                            @{
                                double SumHours = Model.NBTimesheet1.Sum(item => item.work);
                                <text>@SumHours.ToString("F2")</text>
                            }
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Non-Billable</th>
                        <th>Non-Billable</th>
                        <th>Non-Billable</th>
                        <th>Non-Billable</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.NBTimesheet1)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)</td>
                            <td>@(item.billable ? "Billable" : "Non-Billable")</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.projectExternalName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.taskName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.afterHours)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.work)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.assigneeDisplayName)</td>
                            <td>@DateTime.Parse(item.start).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.billingTYPE)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.summaryRootCause)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.declinedReason)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
</div>


I then have a duplication of the above razor logic for timesheet set 1 through to 6.
I then need to merge this table set into 1 and run the following script set.


<script>
    // Function to get current timestamp in 'dd_MM_yyyy_hh:mm:ss' format
    function getFormattedTimestamp() {
        const now = new Date();
        const pad = (num) => (num < 10 ? '0' + num : num);

        const day = pad(now.getDate());
        const month = pad(now.getMonth() + 1); // Month is zero-based
        const year = now.getFullYear();
        const hours = pad(now.getHours());
        const minutes = pad(now.getMinutes());
        const seconds = pad(now.getSeconds());

        return `${day}_${month}_${year}_${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }

    // Function to concatenate the tables' contents
    function concatenateTables() {
        const tableSets = [
            "#timesheetset1 table",
            "#timesheetset2 table",
            "#timesheetset3 table",
            "#timesheetset4 table",
            "#timesheetset5 table",
            "#timesheetset6 table"
        ];
        const concatenatedTable = document.createElement("table");

        tableSets.forEach(selector => {
            const table = document.querySelector(selector).cloneNode(true);
            Array.from(table.rows).forEach(row => {
                const rowType = row.getAttribute('data-row-type');
                if (rowType === 'billable') {
                    row.style.backgroundColor = '#E2EFDA'; // Light green for billable
                } else if (rowType === 'nonbillable') {
                    row.style.backgroundColor = '#DDEBF7'; // Light blue for non-billable
                }
                concatenatedTable.appendChild(row);
            });
        });

        return concatenatedTable;
    }

    function exportToPDF() {
    const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
    const doc = new jsPDF({ orientation: "landscape" });

    const concatenatedTable = concatenateTables();
    const tableData = Array.from(concatenatedTable.rows).slice(1).map((row, rowIndex) => {
        return {
            cells: Array.from(row.cells).map(cell => {
                if (cell.colSpan === 13) {
                    return { content: cell.textContent.trim(), colSpan: 13 };
                }
                return cell.textContent.trim();
            }),
            type: row.getAttribute('data-row-type') // Add the row type for color processing
        };
    });

    const header = [
        ['CODE', 'Billing Type', 'Project', 'NAME', 'NOTE', 'SUPPORT HOURS', 'ACTUAL WORK', 'Assignee', 'START', 'BILLING TYPE', 'APPROVALS', 'SUMMARY ROOT CAUSE', 'DECLINED REASON']
    ];

    doc.autoTable({
        head: header,
        body: tableData.map(row => row.cells.map(cell => {
            if (typeof cell === 'object' && cell.colSpan === 13) {
                return {
                    content: cell.content,
                    colSpan: 13,
                    styles: { halign: 'left', fillColor: [252, 228, 218], textColor: [0, 0, 0], fontStyle: 'bold', fontSize: 6 }
                };
            }
            return cell;
        })),
        startY: 10,
        theme: 'grid',
        styles: {
            fontSize: 5,
            halign: 'left',
            lineWidth: 0.1,
            lineColor: [0, 0, 0]
        },
        headStyles: {
            fillColor: [0, 0, 0],
            textColor: [255, 255, 255],
            lineColor: [0, 0, 0]
        },
        margin: { top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom:20 },
        didParseCell: function (data) {
            if (data.section === 'head') {
                data.cell.styles.fontSize = 6;
            }
        },
        didDrawCell: function (data) {
            const rowType = tableData[data.row.index]?.type; // Retrieve the row type metadata

            if (rowType === 'nonbillable') {
                data.cell.styles.fillColor = [221, 235, 247]; // Light blue for non-billable
            } else if (rowType === 'billable') {
                data.cell.styles.fillColor = [226, 239, 218]; // Light green for billable
            }
        },
        pageBreak: 'avoid',  // Avoid breaking rows across pages
        pageBreak: 'auto',   
    });

    let now = new Date();
    let hours = now.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let minutes = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let seconds = now.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let formattedTime = `${hours}h${minutes}m${seconds}`;
    let filename = `@Model.FileName${formattedTime}.pdf`;

    doc.save(filename);
}


    // Export to Excel function with dynamic file name
    function exportToExcel() {
        const concatenatedTable = concatenateTables();
        const workbook = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(concatenatedTable, { sheet: "Sheet1" });
        // Get the current time
        let now = new Date();
        let hours = now.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        let minutes = now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        let seconds = now.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        let formattedTime = `${hours}h${minutes}m${seconds}`;
        let filename = `@Model.FileName run_${formattedTime}.xlsx`;
        filename = filename.replace(/&#x2B;/g, '+');
        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, filename);
    }
</script>



However on the jspdf my colors are not holding for the billable lines to be green and the nonbillable headers to be blue.
Not sure where I am missing something that is causing the colors not to pull through?
For reference the billable rows are only the headers of the data and not every line.
